# How Direct Trigger an Symbolic Hotkey

Tags: swift, objective-c, hotkeys

Is it possible to directly trigger a Symbolic Hotkey?

To be more specific, I want trigger directly the Symbolic Hotkey 118 -> Switch To Desktop 1

I actually can do this using the a predefined hotkey to dispatch. But how do this Directly?

```
let keyCodeOfNumber1: UInt16 = 18

let keyDownEvent = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: nil, virtualKey: keyCodeOfNumber1, keyDown: true)
keyDownEvent?.flags = CGEventFlags.maskControl
keyDownEvent?.post(tap: CGEventTapLocation.cghidEventTap)

let keyUpEvent = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: nil, virtualKey: keyCodeOfNumber1, keyDown: false)
keyUpEvent?.flags = CGEventFlags.maskControl
keyUpEvent?.post(tap: CGEventTapLocation.cghidEventTap)
```